# Calling ethers.Contract crashes NodeJS

Tags: javascript, contract-invocation, ethers.js

On arbitrum network...

```
const prABI = require('./gmx-interface-master/src/abis/PositionRouter.json');
const PositionRouter = await new ethers.Contract("0xb87a436B93fFE9D75c5cFA7bAcFff96430b09868", prABI, signer)
```

The above code is crashing NodeJS...

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @yunstun You don't need to write `await`